# Error while loading xaml page on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, windows-phone-7

While working on a Windows Phone 7 Application on Visual studio, I am getting this error when I open the XAML designer :

> System.TypeLoadException Cannot find
>   type System.Security.Cryptography.Aes
>   in module mscorlib.dll.

Here is a screenshot 
[image]

I tried deleting various parts of the content, **I even reinstalled Visual Studio 2010 SP1** but still have the same error, any thoughts on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this happen with a new project? Try reinstalling the RTW Toolkit (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce)

Comment: Please post the xaml so we can check it out.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne it happens with EVERY xaml, even an empty page

Comment: Did you re-install just SP1 or the whole of Visual Studio plus SP1?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same type of error (not exactly as yours) for a long time.
I could fix it finally after I loaded the project in "Expression Blend 4.0". Because expression blend can handle and show errors quite better than visual studio designer.

In my case error was regarding one of my static resources in App.xaml

I recommend opening the project in "expression blend" to see which line of your project the error is originating from.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I fixed mine by removing a Drawing DLL reference at "References" then it compiled without a problem. I'd say try removing any Drawing DLL you have at References maybe it will work maybe not but its worth a try.